# Reverting to an old version of my meteor project with git, as well as reverting to old packages

Tags: meteor

I reverted to a previous stable commit of my meteor project, but it doesn't run properly. The version of meteor used is correct (0.8.2), but I think it's using the latest available versions of the mrt packages I've added and this is causing problems to the app.

When I run my meteor app, I get the following error message:
While building package `iron-dynamic-template`:
error: no such package: 'blaze'

Is there a way for me to easily revert back to the exact state of my stable meteor app? I've tried reverting iron-router manually in my smart.json, but it hasn't helped. I get this message when doing mrt install --force:
✓ iron-router
    tag: https://github.com/EventedMind/iron-router/#v0.8.1
Problem installing iron-router
  ✘ [latest] conflicts with [tag: https://github.com/EventedMind/iron-router/#v0.8.1]; keeping [tag: https://github.com/EventedMind/iron-router/#v0.8.1]

Is reverting my app to the stable state possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add this to the `iron-router` section in your `smart.json`

```
iron-router : {
    tag: 'v0.7.1'
}
```

Then run `mrt update`. This will force it to use the older version of iron router which works without the Blaze refactor introduced in 0.8.3

The 0.8.1 version is still meant for 0.8.3. The 0.7x range works with 0.8.0 to 0.8.2